# HTTP POST not working in OWIN Self-Host Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, owin, self-hosting

I am self self hosting a Web API. Any Get Reqeust I make from my integration tests works fine. However any POST request throws connection refused. I can't seem to get a handle on what is happening.

**Error Message**

```
system.Net.HttpRequestException: An error occured while sending the request to the remote server. SocketException: no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused.
```

**Code**

```
using (WebApp.Start<App_Start.TestConfiguration>("http:/localhost:8216"))
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8216");

    var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/MyController", new StringContent("something"));
}
```

**controller**

```
public string Post(string value)
{
    return "Hello!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue and found that it is necessary to use [FromBody] attribute before your method params. In this case it can parse request payload and you can reach your methods

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you're missing a / on:

```
using (WebApp.Start<App_Start.TestConfiguration>("http:/localhost:8216"))
```

it should be http://localhost:8216.

Comment: Yup, That got me through part of it. Now I have a 400 error :(